# Stick element to top of page on scroll and then move it off?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a similar effect to this page, if you go to the manifesto you will see the title on the left sticks [example](https://basedesign.com/about/#manifesto) when the user scrolls. When the panel is at the end the title then moves off.

I want to do this with 3 panels on im unsure how to go about it and the JS ive written isn't applying anything

https://jsfiddle.net/HV9HM/5906/

```
var stickyTop = $('h2').offset().top;

$(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
            $('h2').css({position: "fixed", top: "0px"});
        } else {
            $('h2').css({position: "relative", top: "0px"});
        }
    });
```

---

**Update**

I have built something a bit closer to what I need, the issue I'm having however is that when you scroll down to the next section, I want the title in the first section to stick at the bottom of the parent its in - does this make sense? heres an example jsfiddle.net/HV9HM/5910

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside the ready function because you're trying to access an element that hasn't fully loaded, which is why you're getting an error if you check the console.

```
$(function(){ // need this ready function

    var stickyTop = $('h2').offset().top;

    $(window).on( 'scroll', function(){

        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
            $('h2').css({position: "fixed", top: "0px"});
        } else {
            $('h2').css({position: "relative", top: "0px"});
        };

    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, that was a problem with the error, however this do not solve the fixed and relative problem on scroll

Comment: @Nicholas His code does exactly what it says, but the problem is that he has multiple `h2` tags in the HTML, so the JS doesn't know which one to concern itself with. He should redo the HTML so it's workable.

Comment: Indeed, my bad.

Comment: Thanks @AmericanSlime, Not quite what I was after but thanks for the advice. I have built something a bit closer to what I need, the issue I'm having however is that when you scroll down to the next section, I want the title in the first section to stick at the bottom of the parent its in - does this make sense? heres an example https://jsfiddle.net/HV9HM/5910/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
 var stickyTop="";
 $(window).on( 'scroll', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
             stickyTop = $('h2').offset().top;
            $('h2').css({position: "fixed", top: "0px"});
        } else {
           stickyTop = $('h2').offset().top;
            $('h2').css({position: "relative", top: "0px"});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've updated my question @miguelmachado - I've now got it working better but its still not right https://jsfiddle.net/HV9HM/5910/

Comment: Add a custom attribute to the each h2 element store true for is on top and create a function that for each element sticked to the top adds the padding amount on top of each title.. Can you understand this? Im on phone so nothing much I can help now.